# Trace and SameTest in Union

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

This question is actually two question.

First, I feel so stupid that I just don't understand  the use of the`SameTest` option in `Union`. For example,

```
Union[{0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, -5, 2, 0}, 
  SameTest -> (Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 3] &)]
```

gives the result

```
{-5, 0, 2}
```

Why does this happen?

Second, I tried to use `Trace` to see what the hell going on there. But it gives

[image]

This says nothing! Why can't `Trace` show the operation of `Sametest`?

Comment: This is the correct outcome. Two elements are considered the same if they are the same number mod-3. Therefore, `0` and `3` are the same, for instance. `Union` will kick out all elements that are the same except for one representative, which in the `0`/`3` case is `0`. Under the `Sametest`, `-5`, `0`, and `2` are *not* the same (e.g., mod-3) and that is why they all remain.

Comment: Trace is mostly useful for your own functions and programs. For built-in functions it doesn't show much as they will in general be compiled, so there's not much to see.

Comment: @march What about this `Union[{0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, -5, 2, 0}, 
 SameTest -> (Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 2] &)]`, it gives `{-5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2}`, I am confused again, why this outcome?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries so built-in function is like a black box. There is no way to directly show how they are actually implemented?  I am curious about `Sametest`. Does `SameTest -> (Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 2] &)` first apply `Mod[#, 3]&` then `Mod[#, 2]&` to all list member, then compare them one by one? So for list of n member, there is (n-1)! comparison? How does it determine which element to kickout? It seems that it is related to sorting, because no matter how the original list is ordered, the result is the same. This process is tricky for me.

Comment: As to your earlier comment/question: the result is caused by your strange SameTest. You have to understand that Union is doing a lot of pairwise comparisons and your SameTest says that 2 is not the same as 2 (Mod[2,3]==2 and Mod[2,2]==0, which are not the same). And yes, Union seems to involve sorting as the (documented) result is a sorted list.

Comment: Black box: yes, in most cases you won't be able to see the implementation. Only for certain functions that are implemented in Mathematica code itself will it be possible to trace the internals. And in those case you may have to switch of read protection for that function and/or use a specific option in Trace to show the internals (TraceInternal -> True).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries " switch of read protection for that function and/or use a pacific option in Trace", can you give an example?

Comment: No, I'm currently working on my iPad ( hence the spelling errors, now corrected). But you can lookup the option in the documentation.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe the option is in the manual, but this site has 57 hits on TraceInternal.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries `TraceInternal`!!! This is what I really want after such a long discussion. `TraceInternal` can show how `SameTest` implemented. Now I know it is not implemented (n-1)! times, it is a much clever algorithm. Thank you so much, SjoerdC.deVries!! But I can't understand, why mathematica blocks such a useful option to our users in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Let's label the integers as `list`.

```
list = {0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, -5, 2, 0}
```

Now apply `Mod[#,3]` on each element of that list.

```
listMod = Mod[#, 3] & /@ list
```

Display them in a grid in order to compare

```
Grid[{
  list,
  listMod
  }]
```

The result is:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Union[{0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, -5, 2, 0},
 SameTest -> (Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 3] &)]
```

Produces `{-5, 0, 2}` because -5 represents `Mod[#,3] == 1`, 0 represents `Mod[#,3]==0` and 2 represents `Mod[#,3]`==2.

I am hypothesizing that the selection is based upon the smallest integers that pass the `SameTest`.